# Solr boosting latest documents just not working

Tags: java, search, solr, lucene, solr-boost

I have read many forums and followed a couple of suggestions but I cannot get this to work. I get the results in the reverse order, i.e., the oldest first despite boosting by a non-multivalued date field.

The field specified in schema

```
<field name="last_modified" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

and

```
<fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDateField" omitNorms="true" precisionStep="6" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
```

I have tried with and without `omitNorms` and with varying values for `precisionStep` in case that plays any role in boosting a field.

I have tried all the queries specified [here](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_boost_the_score_of_newer_documents). For instance,

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q={!boost b=$dateboost v=$qq}&dateboost=recip(ms(NOW,last_modified),3.16e-11,1,1)&qq=1234
```

Additionally, I have tried

```
defType=dismax&bf=recip(rord(last_modified),1,1000,1000)^2.5&q=1234
```

I also do a sorting, just plain sorting that discards any relevance scores.

```
q=1234; last_modified asc;
```

Actually, I try both `asc` and `desc`. Quite strange. Why do I still see the latest modified document last and the oldest document first? What is that I am doing wrong? Any help appreciated!

Comment: How does one check contents of the index? When I queried using solr, the dates stored in each document is different.

Answer (score 0):

Unlikely this gives you the sorting order on last_modified

> q=1234; last_modified asc;

Perhaps you meant

```
q=1234&sort=last_modified desc
```

Comment: I tried both. But the order remains. For instance, this order always remains

2014-03-04T04:07:16.515Z //
2014-03-04T04:07:21.677Z //
2014-03-04T04:07:22.433Z //

Comment: I see.Sorting may rely on the precisionStep. The higher the value, the less precisions... You might want to try precisionStep="0" to see if it works. Note that the smaller the  precisionStep, the bigger index size http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/NumericRangeQuery.html

Comment: Oh, well. I had tried with date which has a precision step 0. But the same result. Do you think the format in which the date is stored is alright?